# Javascript - Game Side Collision (Bottom to Top)

Tags: javascript, html, css, collision-detection, game-physics

I am making a game that involves moving a player around with the arrow keys. The player will collide with other objects in the game. I have done the player's right to the object's left collision and the player's left to the object's right collision, yet I cannot figure out how to do the player's bottom to the object's top collision. I have no idea why my code for the bottom to the top collision doesn't work and I have searched the Internet many times to no avail. Your help will be much appreciated.

Here's all of my code so there's no confusion:

**Edit:** My code is now all fixed. It includes collisions on all sides.

```js
var player = document.getElementById("player");
var powerup = document.getElementById("powerup");
var object = document.getElementsByClassName("object");
var player = document.getElementById("player");
for (i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
object[i].style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 250/* window.innerHeight */) + 15 + "px";
object[i].style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 250/* window.innerWidth */) + 15 + "px";
}
setInterval(collisionDetection,1);
function collisionDetection() {
for (i = 0; i < object.length; i++) { 
// Player Right to Object Left
if (player.offsetLeft + player.offsetWidth <= object[i].offsetLeft + 1 &&
    player.offsetLeft + player.offsetWidth >= object[i].offsetLeft &&
    player.offsetTop < object[i].offsetTop + object[i].offsetHeight &&
    player.offsetHeight + player.offsetTop > object[i].offsetTop) {
player.style.left = object[i].offsetLeft - player.offsetWidth + "px";   
}
// Player Left to Object Right
if (player.offsetLeft >= object[i].offsetLeft + object[i].offsetWidth - 1 &&
    player.offsetLeft <= object[i].offsetLeft + object[i].offsetWidth &&
    player.offsetTop < object[i].offsetTop + object[i].offsetHeight &&
    player.offsetHeight + player.offsetTop > object[i].offsetTop) {
player.style.left = object[i].offsetLeft + object[i].offsetWidth + "px";   
}
// Player Bottom to Object Top
if (player.offsetLeft < object[i].offsetLeft + object[i].offsetWidth &&
    player.offsetLeft + player.offsetWidth > object[i].offsetLeft &&
    player.offsetTop + player.offsetHeight >= object[i].offsetTop &&
    player.offsetTop + player.offsetHeight <= object[i].offsetTop + 1) {
player.style.top = object[i].offsetTop - player.offsetHeight + "px";   
}
// Player Top to Object Bottom
if (player.offsetLeft < object[i].offsetLeft + object[i].offsetWidth &&
    player.offsetLeft + player.offsetWidth > object[i].offsetLeft &&
    player.offsetTop <= object[i].offsetTop + object[i].offsetHeight &&
    player.offsetTop >= object[i].offsetTop + object[i].offsetHeight - 1) {
player.style.top = object[i].offsetTop + object[i].offsetHeight + "px";   
}
}
}
function move(event) {
var key = event.keyCode;
if (key == 40) {
player.style.top = player.offsetTop + 1 + "px";
}
if (key == 39) {
player.style.left = player.offsetLeft + 1 + "px";
}
if (key == 38) {
player.style.top = player.offsetTop - 1 + "px";
}
if (key == 37) {
player.style.left = player.offsetLeft - 1 + "px";
}
}
```

```css
html, body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
}
#player {
background: #000;
position: fixed;
height: 10px;
width: 10px;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
}
#powerup {
background: blue;
position: fixed;
height: 10px;
width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body onkeydown="move(event)">
  <div id="player"></div>
  <div class="object" id="powerup"></div>
  <div class="object" id="powerup"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: You might also want to post your code on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for pointers and suggestions on best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the left and right collisions you calculate the new position with `player.offsetWidth`. However in the top collision you are using `player.Height` *which does not exist*, instead of using `player.offsetHeight`

Compare

```
player.style.left = object[i].offsetLeft - player.offsetWidth + "px";
```

with

```
player.style.top = object[i].offsetTop - player.Height + "px";
```